# Convert integer of mixed radix to standard positional numeral system and vice versa

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integers, number-formats, numeral-representations

I have multiple numbers (e.g. `[1, 4, 2]`) where each number can be one of a specified range of numbers (e.g. `[0-1, 0-5, 0-3]`). I think one can represent my so chosen numbers by seeing them as digits of a number in the [mixed radix numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) with different bases for each position. In the above example, the bases would be `[2, 6, 4]` and the number would be `1 4 2`.

With the bases given in this example one could specify `48` different numbers (`2 * 6 * 4`).
If I know the bases, how can I construct an algorithm that converts such a number to another number in a standard positional numeral system (like e.g. decimal, binary or hexadecimal) without just building a big generated lookup table? The conversion has to be bijective and there should not be any gaps - so for this example the mixed radix numbers should be represented by the integers from `0` to (inclusive) `47` in the decimal system.

Actually I want to encode these mixed radix numbers in binary data, so a gapless and bijective conversion to the binary system would be sufficient.

Comment: Generalize the usual base conversion algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in the ranges $x_1 \in \{0,\ldots,b_1-1\},\ldots,x_n \in \{0,\ldots,b_n-1\}$, you can get a number in the range $\{0,\ldots,b_1\ldots b_n-1\}$ using the formula
$$
x_n + b_n x_{n-1} + b_n b_{n-1} x_{n-2} + \cdots + b_n b_{n-1} \cdots b_2 x_1 = \\
x_n + b_n (x_{n-1} + b_{n-1} (x_{n-2} + \cdots )).
$$
The second formula gives an efficient way of calculating the transformation (from inside out), and also hints at calculating the inverse transformation efficiently.

Comment: I already thought that the solution should not be very difficult, but this makes it very clear - thank you!